# Prove that $1 \cdot 1!+2 \cdot 2!+\cdots+n \cdot n!=(n+1)!-1$

Tags: induction, recursion

Prove that $1 \cdot 1!+2 \cdot 2!+\cdots+n \cdot n!=(n+1)!-1$ whenever $n$ is a positive integer.

Basis step:

$P(1)$ is true because $1 \cdot 1!=(1+1)!-1$  evaluate to $1$ on both sides.

Inductive step:

We  assume that $1 \cdot 1!+2 \cdot 2!+\cdots+k \cdot k!=(k+1)!-1$ for some  positive integer $k$.

So under this assumption, it must be shown that $P(k+1)$ is true.

$$1 \cdot 1!+2 \cdot 2!+\cdots+k \cdot k!+(k+1) \cdot (k+1)!=(k+1)!-1+(k+1) \cdot (k+1)!$$

then we have that

$$(k+1)!-1+(k+1) \cdot (k+1)!=(k+1)!(k+2)-1=(k+2)!-1$$

My question is how my teacher got the last step?

$$(k+1)!-1+(k+1) \cdot (k+1)!=(k+1)!(k+2)-1=(k+2)!-1$$

Comment: HINT: $(k+1)\cdot(k+1)!+(k+1)!=(k+1+1)\cdot(k+1)!=(k+2)!$

Answer (score 1):

$$(k+1)!-1+(k+1)(k+1)! =$$
$$=(k+1)!+(k+1)(k+1)! -1=$$
$$=(k+1)![1+(k+1)] -1=$$
$$=(k+1)![k+2] -1=(k+2)!-1$$

Comment: We know that $(n+1)!=(n+1) \cdot n!$, but I can't figure it out how we use this in the proof?

Comment: In the very last step where $n=k+1$

Comment: Okay now understand it. The last thing I want to ask is how $(k+1)(k+1)!=[1+(k+1)]$?

Comment: It's the rule $a+ba=(1+b)a$, where $a=(k+1)!$, and $b=k+1$.

Comment: Okay you just factor :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well we know that $(k+2)! = (k+2)\times(k+1)\times k \times (k-1) ... \times 1$.

However, we know that this can be expressed as $(k+2)(k+1)!$

And so you don't even need to do anything else. You are basically done.

Here is the general formula.

$(k+p)! = (k+p)(k+p-1)!$

and $(k+p-1)! = (k+p-1)(k+p-2)!$

and so on

Answer (score 1):

**First, show that this is true for $n=1$:**

$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{1}k\cdot{k!}=(1+1)!-1$

**Second, assume that this is true for $n$:**

$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}k\cdot{k!}=(n+1)!-1$

**Third, prove that this is true for $n+1$:**

$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n+1}k\cdot{k!}=$

$\color{red}{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}k\cdot{k!}}+(n+1)\cdot(n+1)!=$

$\color{red}{(n+1)!-1}+(n+1)\cdot(n+1)!=$

$(n+1)!\cdot(n+2)-1=$

$(n+2)!-1$

---

Please note that the assumption is used only in the part marked red.